# Understanding mariadb deadlock

Tags: mariadb, mysql-python

Pulled from a (slightly) more complicated real-life scenario. I'm trying to use a row to synchronize access to another (external) resource. It basically works, but I keep seeing a "deadlock" and am trying to understand the cause.

It occurs with at least mariadb versions 10.2.22 (alpine) and 10.1.38 (ubuntu).

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE dlist (
       dnum INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
       dname VARCHAR(64),
       dlnum INTEGER,
       last_update DATETIME,
       CONSTRAINT UNIQUE dlist_nn (dname, dlnum));
```

I have several concurrent processes that are inserting/updating rows in the table. At the same time, I have one process trying to "steal" rows that haven't been updated lately.

The insert:

```
INSERT INTO dlist (dname, dlnum, last_update)
       VALUES (%s, %s, NOW())
       ON DUPLICATE KEY
       UPDATE last_update = NOW(), dnum = LAST_INSERT_ID(dnum);
```

The delete:

```
DELETE FROM dlist
       WHERE (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 SECOND) > last_update
       LIMIT 1
       RETURNING dnum, dname, dlnum;
```

The problem is that I'm seeing fairly frequent deadlocks reported on both Insert and Delete sides. The message as reported by mysql-python:

```
(1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
```

I can get around the issue by retrying but why is this happening -- and is there a way to restructure the SQL to prevent it? I don't get why a single upsert and/or delete is causing a "deadlock".

Full source code to repro (provide username, password, dbname as arguments):

```
import time
import MySQLdb
import os
import sys

user = password = dbname = None

def create_conn():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user=user, passwd=password, db=dbname)
    return conn

def insert_client(dname, dlnum):
    conn = create_conn()
    cmd = """INSERT INTO dlist (dname, dlnum, last_update)
              VALUES (%s, %s, NOW())
              ON DUPLICATE KEY
              UPDATE last_update = NOW(), dnum = LAST_INSERT_ID(dnum);"""
    while True:
        with conn as cursor:
            cursor.execute(cmd, (dname, dlnum))
        time.sleep(2)


def delete_client():
    conn = create_conn()
    cmd = """DELETE FROM dlist
             WHERE (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 SECOND) > last_update
             LIMIT 1
             RETURNING dnum, dname, dlnum;"""
    while True:
        with conn as cursor:
            cursor.execute(cmd)

def main():
    global user, password, dbname
    user, password, dbname = sys.argv[1:4]

    dname = 'foo'
    dlnum = 1

    conn = create_conn()
    with conn as cursor:
        cmd = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dlist;"
        cursor.execute(cmd)
        cmd = """CREATE TABLE dlist (
                    dnum INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    dname VARCHAR(64),
                    dlnum INTEGER,
                    last_update DATETIME,
                    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE dlist_nn (dname, dlnum));"""
        cursor.execute(cmd)
    conn.close()

    nproc = 12
    for _n in range(nproc):
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            insert_client(dname, dlnum)

    # Main process will act as deleter.
    delete_client()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When an update or delete is executing it locks the table. No other operations can take place. The delete is probably doing a full table scan to find a record that meets the where clause criteria. You can offload the responsibility of the primary key's uniqueness elsewhere. Remove AUTO_INCREMENT from your primary key. Remove the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause of your update. Your application or mysql can generate a UUID first, then insert the record into the table using UUID as dnum. Why do you have to delete the records constantly anyways? Could you ignore the old/invalid records instead?

Comment: You are using features such as the returning clause which are available in mariadb only, but not in mysql. Therefore I removed the mysql tag since the codr is not applicable to mysql.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow Did not realize that was mariadb only

Comment: @Noremac - InnoDB does not "lock the table" for updates or deletes.  Why would UUIDs help?

Comment: @RickJames its scanning the table and causing a deadlock. You wouldn't call that a lock? He needs a unique value to keep track of the records. UUIDs/GUIDs can be generated with minimal risk for collision before the insert. It removes the need for an auto incrementing primary key.

Comment: It _may_ help to get rid of the auto_inc PK and promote the UNIQUE to be the PK.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no need for `dnum`; get rid of it.  For the PK, promote the UNIQUE:

```
PRIMARY KEY(dname, dlnum)
```

That may or may not help with the stated problem.  It not, then...

The `DELETE` has no index, so it must scan much, maybe all, of the table.  Solve this by adding

```
INDEX(last_update)
```

**More**

If you can't get rid of `dnum`, then this might help:  Change the set of indexes to

```
PRIMARY KEY(dname, dlnum),
INDEX(dnum),    -- This is the minimum to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
INDEX(last_update)
```

(I don't know whether this would further help avoid deadlocks.  But, I find subtle issues when a table has two unique keys (PK + a UNIQUE).)

Comment: `dnum` is in fact the critical synchronization datum provided by the table: i.e. it's the index which controls access to an external resource. In the actual code, it is being returned via `cursor.lastrowid`. In other words, each inserter is attempting to create/update an external resource which is unique to `(dlname, dlnum)`. The `dnum` returned identifies a name to use for that. The DELETE side then tries to "steal" consume one of those not in use. If another inserter comes around trying to get the same `(dlname, dlnum)`, it just starts a new one (with a new `dnum`).

Comment: However, +1 for the INDEX on `last_update`. With that in place, I'm not seeing the deadlock anymore. I am wondering though if that actually "solves" it or just makes it much less likely to occur.

Comment: Ah. Answered my own question: The deadlock still occurred after running for a couple of minutes. (Also, I had shortened the insert client wait to 0.05 seconds, and added a 0.03 wait on the deleter.) Still the answer was helpful.

Comment: @GilHamilton - Thanks for the feedback on `INDEX(last_update)`.  Your experience is consistent with what I _guessed_.

Comment: @GilHamilton - And I added another possible tip.